# Convert this to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have some Swift code that needs to be written in javascript. I am not sure how to do this. jsonresult is the json data. Can anyone help?

```
let results: NSDictionary = jsonresult["results"] as! NSDictionary

let collection1: NSArray = results["collection1"] as! NSArray

for item in collection1 {
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do some research on your own, like how to convert json to an object, or how to loop through an object?

Comment: Yes I have. I can do it in Swift but cannot work out how to do it in JS. All I need to know are those three lines. @ABakerSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> let results: NSDictionary = jsonresult["results"] as! NSDictionary

```
var results = jsonresult["results"];
```

> let collection1: NSArray = results["collection1"] as! NSArray

```
var collection1 = results["collection1"];
```

> for item in collection1 {

```
for(var item in collection1){
```

*In JS item will the index. So to access the value from the array you need to access the index of the array `collection1[item]`*

If `jsonResult` is an object you can simply access collection1 like this

```
var jsonResult = {
   'results' : 
      { 'collection1': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] }
};

var collection1 = jsonResult.results.collection1;
```

Comment: So var collection1 = jsonResult.results.collection1; can replace the three lines in JS?

Comment: for readability, I will replace first 2 lines with var collection1 = jsonResult.results.collection. Then will use collection1 in third line (or a better var name)